# Expand and Collapse bar charts in amcharts

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

Is it possible to create tree like structure having expand and collapse bar charts?

[image]

All bars represents categories with collapse view. If category has child then [+] will be shown and on click of [+] child bars should be visible and category will expand [-].

Answer (score -1):

Amcharts provide multiple event listeners. For above requirement, you can click on bar itself and add below event in chart.

```
"listeners": [{
            event: 'clickGraphItem',
            method: barClickEvenHandler
        }]
```

or

```
chart.addListener("clickGraphItem", barClickEvenHandler);
```

in function barClickEvenHandler, you can make use of 'event' object and identify based on property whether parent or child is clicked.

Refer below demo http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts2/cV8GG/